# Send Multiple Parameters to SOAP Service via Angular $http POST

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, soap

I am creating one basic Angular js application. There is one simple basic form with 4 parameters. Now i want the details of this form to get saved in my Access Database.

Below is my SOAP Service Method Code :

```
[WebMethod]
        public void RegisterMember(string strFirstName, string strLastName, string strEmailAddress, string strPassword)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                int rowsAffected = 0;
                StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
                sbQuery.Append("INSERT INTO [Members]([FirstName],[LastName],[EmailAddress],[Password],[InsertedOrUpdatedDateTime],[Active]) VALUES (");
                sbQuery.Append(string.Format("\'{0}\',\'{1}\',\'{2}\',\'{3}\',\'{4}\',\'{5}\');", strFirstName, strLastName,
                               strEmailAddress, strPassword, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), "No"));
                Helpers.DAOHelper.InsertData(out rowsAffected, sbQuery.ToString());
                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(rowsAffected.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Failed to Register");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Below is my Angular js Code. Calling custom service from a controller.

```
loginApp.factory("CS_RegisterMember", function ($http, $q, $log) {
    return {
        "RegisterMember": function (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Password) {
            var RegisterMemberResp = $q.defer();
            var a = {
                strFirstName: FirstName, strLastName: LastName,
                strEmailAddress: EmailAddress, strPassword: Password
            };

            alert(a);
            $http({
                url: "http://localhost:61784/Employee.asmx/RegisterMember",
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                params: a
            }).then(function (resp) {
                RegisterMemberResp.resolve(resp);
            },
            function (e_resp) {
                $log.error(e_resp);
                RegisterMemberResp.reject(e_resp);
            })
            return RegisterMemberResp.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

But when i run this i am getting below error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

I am trying this since a week. Searched on various blog but didnt get the solution. Please help me.

Comment: It is not possible to call SOAP API using $http. $http is form REST API's. Try using some soap modules https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap

Comment: Not possible means? We cannot use SOAP API in Angular Js ? or is there anything that i need to change in Configuration file of SOAP Service

Comment: I mean you cant use $http to call soap web services, you need to use additional libraries to support soap in angular js. One of them is https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap. Please check.